# Custom UITableViewCell with data from database

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am making a custom UITableViewCell. So the idea is to make a UITableView with some kind of news in it. This news have a topic and a description. I have a NieuwsTableviewCell class and a FirstViewController which is a UITableViewController. I am working with a PHP file to get my data from the database.
How do I get my news_topic and description for each new row on the labels?

My FirstViewController.m file looks like this.

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "NieuwsTableViewCell.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{

    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void) start {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [self getData:data];

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [super viewDidLoad];
[self start];

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [json count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    NieuwsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray* views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NieuwsTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (UIView *view in views) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Nie_topic"];
                cell = (NieuwsTableViewCell*)view;
            }
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

FirstViewController. h file

```
#define kGETUrl @"http://localhost/getNieuws.php"
@interface FirstViewController : UITableViewController{
     NSMutableArray *json;
}
```

And this is my NieuwsTableViewCell.h file

```
@interface NieuwsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell{
   IBOutlet UILabel *topic;
   IBOutlet UILabel *omschrijving;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *topic;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *omschrijving;

@end
```

Could anybody help ?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly ? What do you obtain on screen when you execute ? Does the [json count] return the right value ? I would suggest you to procceed step by step : First you could try with a standard UITableViewCell (not loaded from xib). If it works, you can introduce your custom cell. If not, the issue is probably related to the data.

Comment: Just a quit tip, you are setting the textLabel of the cell only if the cell is nil. not when there is a cell dequeued.

Answer (score 0):

are u getting any data in this method..?

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data
```

check the array & print each dictionary in it..

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Nie_topic"];
cell = (NieuwsTableViewCell*)view;
```

In the above code, you are setting the properties of a dequeued or null UITableViewCell, and then re-setting the cell variable, overwriting the changes you have made to the textLabel, causing the topic to not be displayed.

Consider the following code. In contrast with the code you are using at the moment, the if statement is called if the tableView has not yet created a reusable cell, and sets the cell to a UITableViewCell subview in the nib that you are loading. Instead of setting the textLabel's text when the cell is nil, we are doing this to every-single cell in order to prevent reuse issues and no topics being shown in the cell.

```
NieuwsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *subViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NieuwsTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in subViews) {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (NieuwsTableViewCell*)view;
        }
    }
}
NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = [info objectForKey:@"Nie_topic"];
```

Edit--- Just realised that this post is ~ 1 year old, it was last updated today which is the reason why I posted an answer. If this benefits anyone, then it was worth it.